# How to add style to lightning combobox?

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning, css, lwc-dom, lightning-combobox

how can I add style to the combobox input and option items?

```
><lightning-layout-item size="12" padding="around-small">
                    <label class="custom-combobox-label slds-form-element__label">Combobox label</label>
                    <lightning-combobox name="issueOptions" placeholder="Which of the following best describes your issue? "
                        class="" options={options} style="line-height: none;"
                        variant="label-hidden" required></lightning-combobox>
                </lightning-layout-item>
```

for example, the placeholder isn't in the middle of the input box, and the dropdown option have small font size, I've tried all methods I can, but no luck, appreciate your help, thanks
[image]